# Is there a way to check for symbol data type?

Tags: scheme

In scheme, is there a way to check if a data type is a symbol?

Some thing like

```
(define symbol-test
  (lambda (s)
    (if (symbol? s)
        #t
        #f)))
```

So if you give like `(symbol-test 'x)` should be `#t`. (even if `x` is not defined)
And this `(symbol-test 3)` or `(symbol-test '(1 2 3))` should be `#f`.

Comment: It seems, that you didn't even tried to search`symbol?`, or run your code in an interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

You actually got it right there. `symbol?` is a standard function in R5RS.

To quote the standard

> procedure: symbol? obj
>   Returns #t if obj is a symbol, otherwise returns #f.

```
(symbol? 'foo)                         ==>  #t
(symbol? (car '(a b)))                 ==>  #t
(symbol? "bar")                        ==>  #f
(symbol? 'nil)                         ==>  #t
(symbol? '())                          ==>  #f
(symbol? #f)                           ==>  #f
```

On a related note, I'd use

```
(define symbol-test symbol?)
```

instead of your current implementation, it's cleaner and easier to understand.